# React Material Theme is not inherited by external dependency

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, material-design

We have a shared npm package which customizes react material button so that it can be used by multiple applications.

For example if my npm package name is `custom-npm-package`

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

function CustomButton(props, ref) {
   return <Button {...props} ref={ref} />;
}

export default React.forwardRef(CustomButton)
```

We bundled this package using `webpack` with `@material-ui/core` as external dependency and published it to npm.

But when we try to use this in our main application, theme is not passed down to the custom button.

For example:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { CustomButton } from 'custom-npm-package';

export default createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#006649',
      light: '#004930',
      dark: '#006649'
    }
  },
  typography: {
    primary: {
      main: '#006649',
      light: '#004930',
      dark: '#006649'
    }
  }
});

function App() {
  return <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CustomButton color='primary' />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
}
```

If I do this expectation is I should see the button with color `#006649` but instead I am getting a button with material default theme color.

It seems custom theme is not inherited by component in the npm package. Can someone help me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `@material-ui/core` installed as a dependency in your npm package (even as dev dependency) this can cause multiple copies of `@material-ui/core` to be loaded which can overwrite the theme.

If you list `@material-ui/core` as a [peer dependency](https://flaviocopes.com/npm-peer-dependencies/) **only** it should be loaded once and it will read the theme from your theme provider in your main app.

```
{
  // package.json
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "1.2.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: I added only as peer dependency. But looks like it does not work.